# Facebook SDK Share meta tags not workings

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, meta-tags

I'm trying to put a facebook share button, but the meta tags are not working.
Here are the meta tags:

```
<meta property="og:url"                content="http://product.local/#/profile.html" />
  <meta property="og:type"               content="article" />
  <meta property="og:title"              content="Product" />
  <meta property="og:description"        content="Look at this product" />
  <meta property="og:image"              content="http://static01.nyt.com/images/2015/02/19/arts/international/19iht-btnumbers19A/19iht-btnumbers19A-facebookJumbo-v2.jpg" />
```

Here is the div for the share button:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://product.local/#/store" data-layout="button_count"></div>
```

I can share the product I want, but with only the basic information. It's not getting the information I used on the meta tags.

This is what appears on the error console:

```
GET www.facebook.com/impression.php/ff26b184f0f14c/?api_key=971260712954084&lid=115&payload=%7B%22source%22%3A%22jssdk%22%7D:1 GET https://www.facebook.com/impression.php/ff26b184f0f14c/?api_key=971260712954084&lid=115&payload=%7B%22source%22%3A%22jssdk%22%7D net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
VM7253:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token _(anonymous function) @ app.js:1
```

Just a note, my project is in localhost for now.

Any help?

Comment: Try this make both url values same `og:url` and `data-href`;

Comment: You are not actually using local URLs, right …?

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 It was my mistake, even with both of them the same, the problem remains.

Comment: @CBroe Right now yes, because I am working in localhost, but when the webapp goes live I will change it of course

Comment: To extract the meta data, Facebook needs to be able to read your URL – and that is of course not possible, if you use “local” URLs.

Comment: @CBroe So I won't be able to test this until it goes online?

Comment: You won’t be able to test this until you make it publicly available on the internet. (A dnydns address might work, if you open your local development server for requests from the internet. Whether that’s a) worth the effort, and b) the possible security implications, is for you to decide.)

Comment: Yes you need to go live to test it because facebook server can't access your local data;